# SMS Gateway using VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I am developing a Short Message Service Gateway using VB.Net, is there any existing free code or e-book or short course about that ?

I don't want to use internet protocol or HTTP but pure protocol using card in modem likely writing short message from mobile phone and send it.

The most important is that I want to send short message from my application developing in VB.Net from my computer and send it to mobile phone.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you something you've already done in VB.Net for your problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick Google search made me find this:
http://www.scampers.org/steve/sms/libraries.htm#gsmcomm